# How to design a datastructure that spits out one available space for each thread in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing

In my Project with CUDA I need to have a data structure(available to all threads in the block)that is similar a "stash". In this stash there are multiple spaces which could be either empty or full. I need this data structure to spit out empty space when each thread asks for. The thread will ask for a space in the stash, put something in, and mark this position as full. I could not use a fifo because fetching from stash is random. Any position(and multiple positions)could be marked as empty or full.

The initial version I have is that I use an array to represent whether the space is empty or not. each thread will loop through each position space(using atomicCAS) until it finds a empty spot. But this algorithm the searching time depends on how full the stash is, which is not acceptable in my design.

How could I design a datastructure that the fetching time and write back time does not depend on how full the stash is?

Does this remind anyone of anything any algorithm similar? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement this with a FIFO containing a list of free locations.

At startup you fill the FIFO with all locations.

Then whenever you want a space, you take the next element from the FIFO .

When you are finished with the slot, you can place the address back into the FIFO again.

This should have O(1) allocation and deallocation time.

Comment: In cuda how could I guarantee that when multiple thread could access this fifo at same time this won't mess up?

Comment: You will need to use an atomic FIFO implementation

Comment: Sounds like a valid solution. I am wondering if there is a faster way without locking the entire fifo though.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a hash table ([SeparateChaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists)) with ThreadID as the key.
It is more or less similar to array of linked lists. This way you need not put a lock on the entire array as you did earlier. Instead, you use atomicCAS only while reading a linkedlist from a specific index. Thereby, you can have n threads running in parallel where array size is n.

Note: The distribution of threads however depends on the hash function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. in your idea, each thread will manage the list separately. Then I can not guarantee that each thread can always get an empty space. Some chains are long some are short. Am I right or I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes! You are right! I did not realize the fact that you had fixed number of open slots (cannot grow dynamically). 

The solution for that would be to keep retrying with KeyValue=KeyValue+1 until you get a free slot. Each time you would be blocking only the list corresponding to KeyValue.

Comment: Now as I mentioned, the operation time is not O(1) any more, it depends on the occupancy of the slots